# Adding NFT to certified collection using the metaplex.nfts().create() function

Tags: metaplex

I am having issues verifying the collection when I mint an NFT. I am using the `metaplex.nfts().create()` function and I am positive the `metaplex.indentity()` has update authority of the collection NFT.
I get the following error.

```
 MetaplexError: TokenMetadataProgram > Cannont Verify Collection in this Instruction
>> Source: Program > TokenMetadataProgram [metaqbxx...x1s]
>> Problem: The program [TokenMetadataProgram] at address [meta...x1s] raised an error of code [74] that translates to "Cannont Verify Collection in this Instruction".
>> Solution: Check the error message provided by the program.
Caused By: CollectionCannotBeVerifiedInThisInstruction: Cannont Verify Collection in this Instruction
```

I also know that everything else involved with the minting of the NFT is fine because when I add the collection with `verified: 0` it works fine.

Am I able to add an NFT to an existing certified collection using the `metaplex.nfts().create()` function? If that is not allowed, what is the best way to do so immediately after minting?

Full stack trace:

```
at RpcClient.parseProgramError (file:///.../node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/rpcModule/RpcClient.mjs:206:28)
      at RpcClient.sendTransaction (file:///.../node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/rpcModule/RpcClient.mjs:48:18)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async RpcClient.sendAndConfirmTransaction (file:///.../node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/rpcModule/RpcClient.mjs:69:23)
      at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (file:///.../node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/TransactionBuilder.mjs:131:22)
      at async file:///.../node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Task.mjs:58:23
      at async Disposable.run (file:///.../node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Disposable.mjs:22:14)
      at async Task.callback (file:///.../node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/plugins/nftModule/NftClient.mjs:48:22)
      at async file:///.../node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Task.mjs:58:23
      at async Disposable.run (file:///.../node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/js/dist/esm/utils/Disposable.mjs:22:14)
      at async mintNft (file:///.../src/mint/mint_lib.js:46:29)
      at async mint (file:///.../src/mint/mint_lib.js:71:12)
      at async Context.<anonymous> (file:///.../test/mint-test.js:27:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to set the collection as verified true without using a verify_collection instruction. This is not possible since the mpl_token_metadata program checks if someone tries to verify a collection without using that type of instruction, [check the onchain code here](https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/src/mpl_token_metadata/assertions/collection.rs.html#27-28).

So the actual way of doing this is create the NFT with the collection not verified (`verified: 0`) and then use **[`createSetAndVerifyCollectionInstruction`](https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html#createSetAndVerifyCollectionInstruction)** providing the [**respective accounts**](https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html#SetAndVerifyCollectionInstructionAccounts).